# What's the best way to model polls?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The domain is like this:

```
class Poll(db.Model):
    question = db.StringProperty()
    ...

class Choice(db.Model):
    poll = db.ReferenceProperty(Poll)
    choice = db.StringProperty()

class Vote(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
    choice = db.ReferenceProperty(Choice)
```

(This is not actually a definitive model, its just pseudo-diagram)

The things I need to query are:

- Total number of votes for each poll on screen
- Total number of votes for each option for each poll on screen
- If the current user voted, for each poll

I have come up with some other schema using shared counters, list properties and none (with my intrinsic limitations) seems to be working. Oh, and of course, it needs to be super fast :)

Could you help me model my data?

Thank you

---

edit: Thanks to @Nick Johnson I can make a more accurate description of my problem, he suggested this schema

```
class Poll(db.Model):
    question = db.StringProperty(indexed=False, required=True)
    choices = db.StringListProperty(indexed=False, required=True)
    votes = db.ListProperty(int, indexed=False, required=True)

class Vote(db.Model):
    # Vote is a child entity of Poll, so doesn't need an explicit reference to it
    # Vote's key name is the user_id, so users can only vote once
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True)
    choice = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
```

The problem with this, is that I can't query efficiently showing if the user has voted or not on a particular poll. Also, I want this shema to resist to lets say 1MM votes per poll or something (maybe I'd never get there, but I would like to aim there)

To solve this I was thinking of adding an EntityIndex like this:

```
class PollIndex(db.Model):
    # PollIndex is child of Poll
    voters = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
    voters_choices = db.ListProperty()
    # other search parameters
```

Then when I have to query for a list of polls I can only do it with 2 queries:

```
# get keys from pollindex where user is not there
# get keys from pollindex where user is there
# grabb all the polls
```

An other cool thing is that if the voters increase in size I can dinamically add more PollIndexes

What do you think of this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer somewhat depends on what you expect the maximum sustained rate of updates to the poll to be. I'll assume initially that it's going to be quite limited (<1 per second typical, with peaks up to 10 per second).

Your design is mostly okay, except for a couple of tweaks:

- Don't store choices as a separate entity, just store them as a list on the poll
- Keep a running total of votes on the Poll entity for fast retrieval

With those changes, your model looks something like this:

```
class Poll(db.Model):
  question = db.StringProperty(indexed=False, required=True)
  choices = db.StringListProperty(indexed=False, required=True)
  votes = db.ListProperty(int, indexed=False, required=True)

class Vote(db.Model):
  # Vote is a child entity of Poll, so doesn't need an explicit reference to it
  # Vote's key name is the user_id, so users can only vote once
  user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True)
  choice = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)

# Here's how we record a vote
def record_vote(poll_key, user, choice_idx):
  # We assume 'user' is an instance of a datastore model, and has a property 'user' that is
  # a users.User object
  poll = Poll.get(poll_key)
  vote = Vote.get_by_key_name(user.user.user_id(), parent=poll)
  if vote:
    # User has already voted
    return
  vote = Vote(key_name=user.user.user_id(), parent=poll, user=user)
  poll.votes[choice_idx] += 1
  db.put([vote, poll])
```

If you need higher throughput, you should modify the `Vote` record to not be a child of `Poll` (and change its key name to incorporate both poll ID and user ID), and then either use write-behind counters with Memcache or a pull queue to aggregate the results into updates to the Poll totals.

Comment: The thing I'm concerned about is showing in a list whether you have voted or not in that particular poll. With this schema I´m stuck with n+1 queries

Comment: If I had a list property with the votes, I could query first for polls  the user has voted and then polls the user hasn't voted, and that would make it 2 queries

Comment: one final thought, what if I was expecting 100.000 votes per poll?

Comment: @fceruti To determine which of a set of polls a user has voted on, you can do a batch get, since you know the keys of the entities that will exist if they have voted. That's a single datastore roundtrip, not one per poll.

Comment: The number of votes you expect don't matter - what matters is the rate at which you expect to receive votes. If you expect 100k votes over a couple of days, that's well under 1QPS, and should work fine with this solution.

Comment: Nick one more followup question. Why is it necessary to store the user field if it's already implicit on the key_name? I can make a query filtered by key_name = 'user_id', can't I?

Comment: @fceruti Yup! You only need to store the user object if you want access to their email address or other fields.